# Lightningchart show axis on series without taking space

Tags: javascript, charts, lightningchart

i'm trying to create transparent axis and show it on the line series. I want to see line series under the axis bar. Is is possible? How can i do it?

for example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible as the charts have a hard definition of "viewport" that only starts after the axes. Anything outside it is not shown.